# My batch code for zipping a folder using 7zip works in command line but not my .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, 7zip

Today I tried out creating a bat to automate a process I have to do all the time.

One problem I have is this code, where I try to create an achieve from a folder and all its subfolders and have it appear in the folder I ran the .bat from. (The same folder where the folder to be zipped is located.)

```
C:\Users\Ann>7za a -tzip Things.zip C:\"Users\Ann\Desktop\Stuff and things\things\"
```

Now this works just fine if I use cmd to run it (it creates the Things.zip in the Users directiory, where 7za.exe is located), but not in my .bat. Instead, when I run my .bat script it creates a 0 KB file called simply "7za" in the folder I ran the .bat from.

Can someone tell me why this is? I've read through most everything I could find on the topic and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Put the appropriate `CD`' command at the top of your 'bat'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would that be? Setting CD and then the path to where the .bat is located (and the folder to be zipped) doesn't work and changing to the user directory just puts the 1 KB 7za file over there.

Comment: Post your exact batch file and indicate how you run it.

Comment: `C:\"Users\Ann\Desktop\Stuff and things\things\"` ?????  `"C:\Users\Ann\Desktop\Stuff and things\things"`

Answer (score 1):

Your bat file shouldn't look like:

```
C:\Users\Ann>7za a -tzip Things.zip C:\"Users\Ann\Desktop\Stuff and things\things\"
```

You're redirecting output `>` from trying to run `c:\users\ann` to `7za a -tzip...` I expect the created file is something like `'ann' is not recognized as an internal or external command...` 
The bat file should just be:

```
@7za a -tzip Things.zip "C:\Users\Ann\Desktop\Stuff and things\things\"
```

If your bat file is in a different directory to `c:\users\ann` then before the 7za line, run `cd c:\users\ann`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes more sense and now I'm getting it better. Is there a way to have 7zip create the .zip in the same directory as the folder that is being zipped? Right now it creates it in Users, where the 7za file is located. I read through the commands for 7zip and I can't find anything that would specify that. Do I have to just move the file with a different command?

Comment: It's probably simpler to use `cd "C:\Users\Ann\Desktop\Stuff and things\"` followed by `C:\Users\Ann\7za a -tzip Things.zip "things\"` instead then.